# LinkButton with click method doesn't work

Tags: 2007, development, custom-actions

I have an issue with LinkButton in my toolbar, basically i deployed a custom action which adds a link button to the menu, this link button on click should do some task like adding an item, but this method is never called.

That is how the code looks like for the link button:

```
public class MyCustomControl: WebControl
    {
        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            base.CreateChildControls();

            LinkButton linkButton = new LinkButton
            {
                Text="Fun"
            };

            linkButton.Click += new EventHandler(linkButton_Click);
            Controls.Add(linkButton);          

        }

        void linkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          //DO SOME ACTIOn
        }
}
```

So the linkbutton is added and everything is ok, but when i click it, it just refreshes the page and that is it.
Nothing happens

Here is the declaration in the custom action:

```
 <CustomAction
        Id="MyCustomAction"
        Title="Fun"
        Description="Lets have fun"
        RegistrationType="ContentType"
        RegistrationId="0x01"
        GroupId="ActionsMenu"
        Location="DisplayFormToolbar"
        Sequence="1000"
        ControlAssembly="Assembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ac112ea8ee9f48g0"
        ControlClass="Assembly.MyNamespace.MyCustomControl">
```

Any idea, what could go wrong?

**Update**:

This link is rendered as  with this href:

> javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new
>   WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$m$g_e00f473f_0a92_40aa_9805_03114c3f2da5$ctl00$ctl01$ctl00$toolBarTbl$RptControls$Fun", "", true, "", "", false, true))

Comment: when you load the page check ctl00$m$g_e00f473f_0a92_40aa_9805_03114c3f2da5$ctl00$ctl01$ctl00$toolBarTbl$RptControls$Fun exists, then click the button and check the same ID exists... if it doesnt then thats pointing to your issue.

Comment: But if it does what then?

Comment: I just checked and when the page first loads and without clicking on the link, it already has this kind of information, this href ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of time spending researching this issue, I finally found the solution, basically what i had to do is on OnLoad method, i had to ensure that the controls are bound, basically by only doing this:

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        EnsureChildControls();
    }
```

This way the link button worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

give the link button an ID - i've had this issue before where the controls ID is autogenerated and cant map an event back to it on postback.

I.e. change:

```
LinkButton linkButton = new LinkButton
{
    Text="Fun"
};
```

To

```
LinkButton linkButton = new LinkButton
{
    Text="Fun",
    Id="CustomActionLinkButton"
};
```

Alternatively use the OnInit() method

```
private LinkButton linkButton;

protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
   base.OnInit(e);
   linkButton = new LinkButton
   {
       Text="Fun",
       Id="CustomActionLinkButton"
   };
   linkButton.Click += new EventHandler(linkButton_Click);
}

protected override void CreateChildControls()
{
    base.CreateChildControls();
    Controls.Add(linkButton);          
}
```

Comment: Yep, I have tried with your approach but still same, just a refresh and my event wasn't called. :(

Comment: tried it, and still no success, really strange, have no idea why :(